# C++ Custom Shell: Stdin Redirection Method Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, shell, segmentation-fault, io-redirection, execvp

I am currently creating my own simple shell in C++ that implements piping, < , >, and >> redirection without using system.

All my implementations work, but one. I am getting a segmentation fault with my standard input redirection implementation. Example: `cat < file.txt`

My shell code parses prompt input(argv/argc) in another method and calls an IO redirect method. Each redirect feature has its own method.

**My stdin IO redirect method takes a double char pointer command and double char pointer file as parameters.**

```
void redirect(char** cmd, char** file) {
  //declare variables   
  int fd; 
  char c;   
  pid_t pid; 

  fd = open(file[0], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);

  //opens if no error
  if (fd < 0) {
      printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(1);
  }

  dup2(fd, 0); 

  execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
  perror(cmd[0]);       /* execvp failed */
  exit(1);
}
```

My shell program compiles and runs successfully. However, when I enter:

```
cat < file.txt
```

Segmentation fault(core dumped)

*My other IO implementations for redirection have the same exact parameters passed and work, so I think my stdin "<" method is incorrectly implemented.*

**Works**

1. cat > file.txt
2. cat >> file.txt
3. cat f.txt > file.txt
4. cat f.txt >> file.txt
5. pipe (|) method works

I would really appreciate any clarification. I am a little confused after researching the `dup2` and `execvp` forums. Please tell me if there is something wrong with my method implementation.

**Main Method**

```
373 //main method                                                                                                                                                                  
374 int main() {
375   char *argv[ARGSMAX], *p1[ARGSMAX], *p2[ARGSMAX];
376   Pipeline pipe_redirect;
377   int argc;
378   //gets present working directory                                                                                                                                             
379   char *name = NULL;
380   size_t size = 0;
381   name = getcwd(name,size);
382   // prompt until user quits                                                                                                                                                   
383   while (true) {
384     cout << "1730sh:" << name << "$ ";
385 
386     //read user input                                                                                                                                                          
387     argc = readInput(argv);
388 
389     //parse input                                                                                                                                                              
390     pipe_redirect = parse(argc, argv, p1, p2);
391     if (pipe_redirect == PIPE)
392       pipeD(p1, p2);
393     else if (pipe_redirect == APPEND)
394       append(p1, p2);
395     else if (pipe_redirect == TRUNCATE)
396       redirect(p1,p2);
397     else if(pipe_redirect == TRUNCOUT)
398       truncOut(p1,p2);
399     else if(pipe_redirect == ETRUNCATE)
400       eTruncate(p1,p2);
401     else if(pipe_redirect == EAPPEND)
402       eAppend(p1,p2);
403     else
404       runP(argc, argv);
405 
406     // set argv to null                                                                                                                                                        
407     for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
408       argv[i] = NULL;
409   }
410   return 0;
411 }
```

Comment: Since it writes "core dumped", you now have a `core` file. You might want to use gdb to examine where (at which line in code) the segmentation fault happened. This is a very important addition to your debugging effort. [edit] your question to include this info.

Comment: Okay! Thank you for the tip. I will get right on it. I will post results in a moment.

Comment: @D_Toy, Just as a sanity check, you're not forget to set the last element of the `cmd` array of pointers to the null pointer, right?

Comment: Sorry computer shut down. Pretty sure I did, but let me double check. I feel that my other methods wouldn't be working if that was the case. They call execvp(cmd[0],cmd) as well. @Paulo1205 BUT you never know haha so let me check.

Comment: @Paulo1205 I added my main method that deals with the cmd... are you saying that I need to set the last element of p1?

Comment: @D_Toy, The code you added does not directly calls the `redirect` function, and I have no idea of what you mean with your `p1` and `p2` arrays.  But my sanity check was that you have to make sure that whatever you send as the second argument to any of the `execv*()` functions is a NULL pointer-terminated array of pointers to characters (each pointing to a string, except for the last).

Comment: @Paulo1205 Okay, I checked. There is a NULL pointer-terminated array in the second arguement of the execvp() function.